# Is there a way to find out what type of bytes are returned from a ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java

I'm simply trying to figure out what kind of bytes are in a `ByteArrayInputStream`. In one case, I store a `byte[]`, and in another case I store a `Hashmap`. The following code fails in `ObjectInputStream` in the case of a `byte[]` only, and succeeds when its a `Hashmap`.  Is there a way to find out what type of bytes are returned from a `ByteArrayInputStream`?

```
Object object = null;
try {
    final ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    final ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(byteIn);
    object = in.readObject();
    in.close();
    byteIn.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
    // Sadly, when ByteArrayInpuStream is instantiated I can not detect whether its an object of bytes or just bytes
    // If anyone know of a better way?
    if(!e.getMessage().contains("invalid stream header")) {
        Logger.error(logStringFormatter(DFLT_WIDTH, "Exception", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
return object;
```

Comment: `object.getClass()` ?

Comment: The exception occurs before I am able to find out what the class name of the object.  It dies right after final ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

Comment: You should look into serialization. If you don't want to use serialization, you'll have to manually maintain what kind of object you stored in your bytes.

Comment: If you look carefully, the object is already being serialized in one case.  The answer is that I would simply need to created a wrapper object for the byte[] that's serialized.  But, I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution is to create a serialize object for both cases.  It doesn't seem to be  way within the Java language specification to do what I want. In the long run, it is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you serialized a byte[] object, or you mean you have raw bytes in the stream? An object stream starts with aced0005, raw bytes won't.

Comment: In one case, I wrote simple byte[] to a file.  In another case, the same file I serialize an object and saved it.  Now, I want an API to tell me whether is was a byte[] or a serialized object. I believe I will have to save they byte[] as a serialiable object and that will get answer both problems.